# Is there any way to get the pull request description using a command?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

I have a PR and I have to get the description of the PR.

I know that there will be a way to get this using API., but is there any git command where I can use it to get the PR details of the branch?

Answer (score 1):

you could use [github cli](https://github.com/cli/cli)

then:

`gh pr status`